# How to remove line break if it is repeated more than 2 times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Input: `"Some text \n\n\nSome text"`

Output: `"Some text \n\nSome text"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#gsub-method) to replace 3 or more `\n`'s with `\n\n`:

```
str = "Some text \n\n\nSome text"

str.gsub(/\n{3,}/, "\n\n")
#=> "Some text \n\nSome text"
```

or you could use a *positive lookbehind* to match 1 or more `\n` that are preceded by `\n\n` and remove the excess `\n`'s:

```
str.gsub(/(?<=\n\n)\n+/, '')
#=> "Some text \n\nSome text"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = 'Some text \n\n\n\n\nSome text';
while my_string.count('\n') > 2
   my_string = my_string.reverse.sub('\n', '').reverse;
end

puts my_string;
```

Comment: Within single quotes, a ``\`` is treated as a literal backslash. Use double quotes instead.

Comment: why do u use reverse?